# How do I redirect AWS S3 requests for missing files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using S3 to store several hundred thousand images in a bucket, organized into several sub folders.  Whenever a client application requests an image in any of these folders that is not found, I would like S3 to return a blanktile.png stored in the root of the same s3 bucket.  I have configured the bucket's static web site properties with the following redirect rule but I still get 403's.  All files in the bucket including the blanktile.png are marked as public.

```
[
    {
        "Condition": {
            "HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals": "403"
        },
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "blanktile.png"
        }
    }
]
```

Good image: https://dmtiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ALPWater/15/7696/21100.png

Missing image: https://dmtiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ALPWater/15/7696/random.png

Replacement file: https://dmtiles.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/blanktile.png

Comment: Can you show us the URL you are using to access the object? Does it have `s3-website` in the URL?

Comment: Added URL examples above.  No it does not have "s3-website" in the URL

Comment: Thanks John.  Changing the "s3" to "s3-website" made it work.  This link helped me also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to redirect to a 404 page is only available when using the Static Website URL. See: [Configuring a custom error document - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/CustomErrorDocSupport.html)

The URL should look like:

```
http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com/object_key
```